# Applying Math.random() to call arrays

Tags: java, android, arrays, random

Is it possible to use the Math.random() command to call random lines from an array or is there actually another method for this? Sorry if this have an obvious-answer but I am entirely new to programming. My codes as follows:

```
final float line_positions[][] = new float[][] {
        //X coordinate of line, Y Coordinate of hole
}
        { 600, 0.5f },
        { 900, 0.3f },
        { 1200, 0.2f },
        { 1500, 0.3f },
        { 1800, 0.1f },
        { 2100, 0.4f },
        { 2400, 0.5f }

};

......

int temp_score = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < line_positions.length; i++) {

float y = line_positions[i][Y] * ScreenHeight();
float x = ScreenX((int) line_positions[i][X] * ScreenWidth() * 0.0015f);

}
```

Comment: So you want your `i` to be replaced by a random number? But still retrieve all `line_positions` in a loop?

Answer (score 2):

Use Random for it.

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int randomRow = rnd.nextInt(line_positions.length);
```

If you however want every row only once, then I'd suggest casting the array to list, use `Collections.shuffle()` to randomize and iterate over the list.